# Button Arguments binding

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to bind `item[0]` to `CommandArgument` such that when it reaches to code level, I will be able to retrieve my `item[0]` for processing.

Tried removing the quotes but it did not work because of the `runat="server"` tag.
The code provided retrieves the literal value which is `<%=Eval("item[0]")%>`

```
<% foreach (List<String> item in arlist3) { %>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <%= item[0] %>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%= item[1] %>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" CommandArgument='<%=Eval("item[0]")%>' CommandName="ThisBtnClick" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-xl" OnClick='Delete'/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <% } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this`enter code here`

```
protected void Delete(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button )(sender);
    var itemValue= btn.CommandArgument;    
}
```